# Difference between a pointer in C++, and a pointer in Assembly languages?

Tags: c++, pointers, assembly

Also, far and near pointers ... can anyone elaborate a bit?

In C++, I have no clue on how pointers work in the direct opcode level, or on the circuit level, but I know it's memory accessing other memory, or vice-versa, etc.

But in Assembly you can use pointers as well.

Is there any notable difference here that's worth knowing, or is it the same concept? Is it applied differently on the mneumonics level of low-level microprocessor specific Assembly?

Comment: Near and Far is a thing of the past (mostly). A pointer is just a memory address, a number.

Comment: Aside from pointer arithmetics, I've learned they are the same, just an adress in the memory space. I'd guess that all pointers in C are far pointers by nature, but may be optimized by the compiler to be near pointers.

Comment: The only difference between C and assembly is that C pointers have an associated type. Thus arithmetic means slightly different things (the compiler will use the type information to make sure the stride is correct for the type).

Answer (score 5):

Near and far pointers were only relevant for 16 bit operating systems. Ignore them unless you really really need them. You might still find the keywords in today's compilers for backwards compatibility but they won't actually do anything. In 16-bit terms, a `near` pointer is a 16-bit offset where the memory segment is already known by the context and a `far` pointer contains both the 16-bit segment and a 16-bit offset.

In assembler a pointer simply points to a memory location. The same is true in C++, but in C++ the memory might contain an object; depending on the type of the pointer, the address may change, even though it's the same object. Consider the following:

```
class A
{
public:
    int a;
};

class B
{
public:
    int b;
};

class C : public A, B
{
public:
    int c;
};

C obj;
A * pA = &obj;
B * pB = &obj;
```

`pA` and `pB` will not be equal! They will point to different parts of the `C` object; the compiler makes automatic adjustments when you cast the pointer from one type to another. Since it knows the internal layout of the class it can calculate the proper offsets and apply them.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, pointer is something that allows you to access something else, because it points to it.
In a computer, the "something" and the "something else" are memory contents. Since memory is accessed by specifying its memory address, a pointer (something) is a memory location that stores the memory address of something else.
In a programming language, high level or assembler, you give memory addresses a name since a name is easier to remember than a memory address (that is usually given as a hex number). This name is the name of constant that for the compiler (high level) or the assembler (machine level) is exactly the same as the hex number, or, of a variable (a memory location) that stores the hex number.
So, there is no difference in the concept of a pointer for high level languages like C++ or low level languages like assembler.

Answer (score 0):

Re near/far:

In the past, some platforms, notably 16-bit DOS and 16-bit Windows, used a concept of memory segments. Near pointers were pointer into an assumed default segment and were basically just an offset whereas far pointers contained both a segment part and an offset part and could thus represent any address in memory.

In DOS, there were a bunch of different memory models you could choose from for C/C++ in particular, one where there was just one data segment and so all data pointers were implicitly near, several where there was only one code segment, one where both code and data pointers were far, and so on.

Programming with segments is a real PITA.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what everyone said regarding near/far: the difference is that in C++, pointers are typed - the compiler knows what they are pointing at, and does some behind the scenes address arithmetics for you. For example, if you have an `int *p` and access `p[i]`, the compiler adds 4*i to the value of `p` and accesses memory at that address. That's because an integer (in most modern OSes) is 4 bytes long. Same with pointers to structures/classes - the compiler will quietly calculate the offset of the data item within the structure and adjust the memory address accordingly.

With assembly memory access, no such luck. On assembly level, technically speaking, there's almost no notion of variable datatype. Specifically, there's practically no difference between integers and pointers. When you work with arrays of something bigger than a byte, keeping track of array item length is your responsibility.